# What is wrong with my join in this query?

Tags: sql

Im practicing basic SQL with this site http://www.sqlishard.com/Exercise

Here is the question:

S5.0 - INNER JOIN

> Now that we can pull data out of a single table and qualify column
>   names, let's take it a step further. JOIN statements allow us to
>   'join' the rows of several tables together using a condition to define
>   how they match one another. SELECT [columns] FROM FirstTable INNER
>   JOIN SecondTable ON FirstTable.Id = SecondTable.FirstTableId
>
> Try using the INNER JOIN syntax to SELECT all columns from the
>   Customers and Orders tables where the CustomerId column in Orders
>   matches the Id column in Customers. Since both tables have an Id
>   column, you will need to qualify the Customers id in the WHERE clause
>   with either the table name or a table alias.

Here is my answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON c.ID = o.ID
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.ID
```

The site says im wrong? Could anyone explain where i'm going wrong?

EDIT: I see now I dont need the WHERE clause, but the question states..

> you will need to qualify the Customers id in the WHERE clause with
>   either the table name or a table alias.

Hence my confusion.  Thanks none the less.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is redundant. The `ON` part of the join is sufficient

Comment: @KenKeenan - Check again, the `ON` clause is incorrect, the `WHERE` clause contains the correct predicate.

Comment: How come? According to the question I need to qualify the the Customers ID in there WHERE clause?

Comment: @MatBailie, as the question states, "Since both tables have an Id column", I'm assuming `ON c.ID = o.ID` is OK. But the question is very poorly phrased, referring to a `WHERE` clause where none is needed...

Comment: @DavidFolksman - The question is badly worded.  It's trying to refer back to things you needed to do in previous questions.

Comment: @KenKeenan - The orders table also has a `CustomerID` field.  `Customer.ID` is not going to relate to `Order.ID` if there is also `Order.CustomerID`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT c.ID,o.ID
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON o.CustomerID = c.ID
```

or using where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
where o.CustomerID = c.ID
```

Comment: Im just confused because the question states i need to qualify the table names in the WHERE clause

Comment: @Dijkgraaf,order id and customer id are not the same thing. You don't join them together.

Comment: Just as an added question:  What is the need for a join when you can just specify two tables in the FROM clause?

Comment: @DavidFolksman - The syntax in the second query was replaced by the syntax in the first query in the `ANSI-92` standard *(As in 1992)*.  It is more explicit, maintainable, and better suited to more complicated queries.  Do not invest time learning the `SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 WHERE ...` notation, except maybe if you are studying recent history.

Comment: @DavidFolksman It's the same as `INNER JOIN` but using old sql standard of joins. I prefer new standard - JOIN clause as 1st solution above.

Comment: @DavidFolksman as MatBailie said `Do not invest time learning`

Comment: Very interesting.  Can you recommend any sites like the one above where I can practice more complex joins?

Comment: [See this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) or [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp)

Answer (score 3):

If you use JOIN.. ON, you do not need where clause